# MIT 6.00 Newton's Method in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, newtons-method

This is part of the second problem set for MIT's OCW 6.00 Intro to Computation and Programming using Python. First, I created a function that evaluates a polynomial for a given x value. Then a function that computes the derivative for a given polynomial. Using those, I created a function that evaluates the first derivative for a given polynomial and x value.

Then I tried to create a function to estimate the root of any given polynomial within a tolerance (epsilon).

Test case is at bottom with expected output.

I am new to programming and new to python, so I have included some comments in the code to explain what I think the code should be doing.

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):
""" Computes the polynomial function for a given value x. Returns that value."""
answer = poly[0]
for i in range (1, len(poly)):
    answer = answer + poly[i] * x**i
return answer


def compute_deriv(poly):
"""
#Computes and returns the derivative of a polynomial function. If the
#derivative is 0, returns (0.0,)."""
dpoly = ()
for i in range(1,len(poly)):
    dpoly = dpoly + (poly[i]*i,)

return dpoly

def df(poly, x):
"""Computes and returns the solution as a float to the derivative of a polynomial function
"""
dx = evaluate_poly(compute_deriv(poly), x)
#dpoly = compute_deriv(poly)
#dx = evaluate_poly(dpoly, x)
return dx




def compute_root(poly, x_0, epsilon):
"""
Uses Newton's method to find and return a root of a polynomial function.
Returns a float containing the root"""
iteration = 0
fguess = evaluate_poly(poly, x_0) #evaluates poly for first guess
print(fguess)
x_guess = x_0 #initialize x_guess
if fguess > 0 and fguess < epsilon: #if solution for first guess is close enough to root return first guess
    return x_guess
else: 
    while fguess > 0 and fguess > epsilon:
        iteration+=1
        x_guess = x_0 - (evaluate_poly(poly,x_0)/df(poly, x_0))
        fguess = evaluate_poly(poly, x_guess)
        if fguess > 0 and fguess < epsilon:
            break #fguess where guess is close enough to root, breaks while loop, skips else, return x_guess
        else:
            x_0 = x_guess #guess again with most recent guess as x_0 next time through while loop
print(iteration)
return x_guess




#Example:
poly = (-13.39, 0.0, 17.5, 3.0, 1.0)    #x^4 + 3x^3 + 17.5x^2 - 13.39
x_0 = 0.1
epsilon = .0001
print (compute_root(poly, x_0, epsilon))
#answer should be 0.80679075379635201
```

The first 3 functions return correct answers, but compute_root (Newton's method) does not seem to enter the `while` loop because when I run the cell `print(iteration)` prints 0. I would think that since `if fguess > 0 and fguess < epsilon:` should return `false` for the test case (statement `print(fguess)` prints `-13.2119`), the interpreter would go to `else` and enter the `while` loop until it finds a solution that is within epsilon of 0.

I have tried eliminating the first `if` `else` conditions so that I only have one `return` statement and I get the same problem.

What could be causing the function to skip the `else` case / `while` loop altogether? I'm stumped!

Thanks for looking and/or helping!

Comment: A small but significant observation: you don't access the 1st (element with index `0`) of any array. It should be `for i in range (len(poly)):` not `for i in range (1, len(poly)):`. Change the code in your polynomial and derivative calculation methods to reflect this.

Comment: You are supposed to do the problem sets by yourself.

Comment: It should be `abs(fguess) < epsilon` as condition for the root. At the moment you exclude `-epsilon < fguess < 0` as approximate solutions.

Comment: @EvilTak: No, those loops are correct for polynomial evaluation resp. construction of derivative coefficients.

Comment: Padraic,

I appreciate your dedication to academic integrity but given limited resources I decided to follow the policy:

From the EdX Collaboration Guidelines: "It is ok to have someone show you a few steps of a solution where you have been
stuck for a while, provided of course that you have attempted to solve it yourself
first without success."
From Collaboration Policy on ocw.mit.edu: "Our policy is simple: unless otherwise noted in the assignment itself, feel free to collaborate with each other on all the individual problem sets, but note with whom you collaborated."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be just a small oversight. Notice how `fguess` is printed with a value of -13.2119. In your `while` condition (in `else` from `compute_root`) you require `fguess > 0 and fguess < epsilon`, which is not met so nothing is done further and you exit without iterations.

Instead:

```
while fguess < 0 or fguess > epsilon:
```

Will give you what you need:

```
-13.2119
7
0.806790753796352
```